# I am requesting data from an API. Currently, I am getting data as an array of objects but I'm not able to render output on the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code which I have written to get the details of the match from the API. I am getting the data and converting it into JSON format. I am able to add data to the match array, but I can't render it to screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    match: [
      { id: '12', stat: 'he', score: 's',description:'sds'},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''}

    ],
    otherState: 'some other value'
  }

  GetMatchNumber = async () => {
    const responseofmatchno = await fetch(`https://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey={API_KEY}`);
    const dataofmatchno = await responseofmatchno.json(); 
    const length = dataofmatchno.matches.length;
    var actual_length=0;
    var p=0;
    let true_value = "true";
    while(++p < length)
    {
      if((dataofmatchno.matches[p].matchStarted.valueOf()) === (dataofmatchno.matches[0].matchStarted))
      {
        actual_length = actual_length + 1;
      }
    }
    let i = 0;
    let j=0;
    while(++i < 4)
    {
      j=dataofmatchno.matches[i].unique_id;
      this.state.match[i].id=(dataofmatchno.matches[i].unique_id);
      console.log(this.state.match[i].id);
      const responseofmatchdetails = await fetch(`http://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?unique_id=${j}&apikey={API_KEY}`);
      const dataofmatch = await responseofmatchdetails.json();
      this.state.match[i].stat=(dataofmatch.stat);
      console.log(this.state.match[i].stat);
      this.state.match[i].score=(dataofmatch.score);
      console.log(this.state.match[i].score);
      this.state.match[i].description=(dataofmatch.description);
      console.log(this.state.match[i].description);
    }
  }
  render () {
    console.log(this.state.match[0].id);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
        <p>This is really working!</p>
        <p>{this.state.match[0].id}</p>
        <button onClick= {this.GetMatchNumber()}></button>
        <Person 
          id={this.state.match[0].id} 
          stat={this.state.match[0].stat} />
        <Person 
          id={this.state.match[1].id} 
          stat={this.state.match[1].stat} />
        <Person 
          id={this.state.match[2].id} 
          stat={this.state.match[2].stat} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the data I am getting. I am getting the match unique id and through which I am getting the the details of th match such as stats, scorecard, summary etc. It is printing in the console but not rendering on the page.

```
1197802
App.js:51 Otago Women won by 31 runs
App.js:53 Canterbury Women 91/10 * v Otago Women 122/7 
App.js:55 Canterbury Women 91/10 * v Otago Women 122/7 
App.js:46 1187027
App.js:51 Australia won by 10 wickets (with 74 balls remaining)
App.js:53 India 255/10  v Australia 258 *
App.js:55 India 255/10  v Australia 258 *
App.js:46 1195608
App.js:51 Heat won by 7 wickets (with 28 balls remaining)
App.js:53 Brisbane Heat 114/3 * v Adelaide Strikers 110/10 
App.js:55 Brisbane Heat 114/3 * v Adelaide Strikers 110/10
```

Comment: You are directly mutating the state, you should *never* do this. It's why your state values aren't showing up on screen. You instead need to update your state using `this.setState` function. Also you should NOT update the state in a loop, since it means your component will re-render every loop iteration, which can cause performance issues.

Comment: Now I am getting this error                                                                                    App.js:45 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: Don't do side-effects in the render function, use a lifecycle function, like `componentDidMount`. Don't use `"true"` when you mean `true`. Should also not make a bunch of async fetch requests within a loop, instead queue them up into an array and `Promise.all` them to process all the requests in bulk when they all resolve. You should then be able to consolidate the state update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render function should be a pure function returning a result to display, there should be no side-effects such as fetching data. Instead, use one of the react component lifecycle functions (or callback) to issue side-effects and/or update state. You also are directly mutating state.

First compute an entire object you wish to set state to/with and call `setState` with the new state object. In this case, you can queue up all your fetch requests and process them "in bulk" using `Promise.all`. I also suggest surrounding all your async processing with a try/catch in case errors happen so you can handle it and keep your app on the happy path.

Also, ensure you are setting the button's `onClick` callback correctly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    match: [
      { id: '12', stat: 'he', score: 's',description:'sds'},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''},
      { id: '', stat: '', score: '',description:''}

    ],
    otherState: 'some other value'
  }

  getMatchNumber = async () => {
    const responseOfmatchNo = await fetch(`https://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey={API_KEY}`);
    const dataOfMatchNo = await responseOfmatchNo.json();

    const resolvedFetchedJSON = await Promise.all(
      // map data objects to fetch requests, returns json data
      dataOfMatchNo.matches.map(request => {
        return fetch(`http://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?unique_id=${request.unique_id}&apikey={API_KEY}`)
        .then(response => response.json());
      })
    );

    // at this point I think you have the array of JSON data you were copying previously
    this.setState({ match: resolvedFetchedJSON });

    /**
     * NOTE: if you want to keep existing matches in state, i.e. merge in new data then
     * this.setState(prevState => ({ match: [...prevState.match, ...resolvedFetchedJSON]}));
     */
  }

  render () {
    console.log(this.state.match[0].id);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
        <p>This is really working!</p>
        <p>{this.state.match[0].id}</p>
        {/* <button onClick= {this.GetMatchNumber()}></button> */}
        {
          /**
           * Don't invoke onClick callback immediately, either
           *  - define in-line callback
           *    <button onClick= {() => this.GetMatchNumber()}></button>
           *  - or set callback as your function, notice no parans on function 
           *    <button onClick= {this.GetMatchNumber}></button>
           */
        }
        <button onClick= {this.GetMatchNumber}></button>
        <Person 
          id={this.state.match[0].id} 
          stat={this.state.match[0].stat} />
        <Person 
          id={this.state.match[1].id} 
          stat={this.state.match[1].stat} />
        <Person 
          id={this.state.match[2].id} 
          stat={this.state.match[2].stat} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working fine , but it is taking little more time to copy the contents. Is there any way to reduce the delay??

Comment: Here in the above code I have only 5 objects of match type. Can you please suggest a proper way where i will have object of match type depending upon the number of match being played right now.

Comment: There might not be much you ca do for the delay, which I assume you are referring to  network latency and server response time. I don't quite follow your second question. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Is there any better way to declare object array (Here I have array of "match" object having properties like stat, description etc) than what I have done here? Something dynamic which will create the object depending on the number of match being played? Suppose there are 10 matches going on than the size of array object( here match) should be 10, I don't have to primarly declare the size of array.(Here my array size is 5).

Answer (score 0):

Try the API call in componentDidMount since it will be called once(first render only) then update state using this.setState.